# Are $f,g$ Lipschitz if there is $K\geq 0$ s.t. $d(f(x) , f(y)) + d(g(x), g(y)) \leq K d'(x,y)$ for all $x,y$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Assume that $f,g : X \to Y$ are functions between metric spaces. Assume that there is $K \geq 0$ such that $d_Y(f(x) , f(y)) + d_Y(g(x), g(y)) \leq K d_X(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$. Does this mean that $f,g$ must be Lipschitz? If so, what is the easiest way to see it?

EDIT: I changed a sign, this alters the question completely. But it now reads correctly.

Comment: Yes, of course, since it implies both $d(f(x), f(y) )$  and $d(g(x), g(y) )$   are $\le K \cdot d(x,y)$ ( note that distances are numbers $\ge 0$ ).

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: Yes, for positive numbers $a$, $b$ we have $a\le a+b$, $b\le a+b$ so $a\le a+b$, $a+b\le c$ implies $a\le c$. Same for $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $f$ any non-Lipschitz function, and take $g = f$.

**Edit:** The answer to the corrected question, as already given in comments by @orangeskid, is yes: if $d(f(x), f(y)) + d(g(x), g(y)) \leq K d(x,y)$, then a fortiori since metrics are non-negative, $d(f(x), f(y))\leq K d(x,y)$, so $f$ is Lipschitz. The same holds of course for $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see I made a stupid mistake which I fixed now. I got the sign wrong in this part: $d_Y(f(x) , f(y)) + d_Y(g(x), g(y)) \leq K d_X(x,y)$.